# export MySql database with cmd

Tags: export, cmd, mysql

I'm using MySql 5.1 version and I'm trying to export mydatabase by cmd ,when I wrote this command :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqdump -uroot -ppassword mydatabase >mydatabase.sql
```

I get an Error

> Access is denied

I don't Know what the problem 
Help Pleas.....

Comment: Try `mysql -u {username} -p`, can you log in with your username and password?

Comment: did you try to login by mysql-clint with this conditionals ?

Comment: Actually,I can log in to mysql server with my user name and password ,but when I wrote it in the mysqldump I get this error,I'm sorry don't Know about mysql-clint ??

Answer (score 0):

What's your permissions on the directory you're running this command from?  It may be trying to write the mydatabase.sql file to a directory you don't have permissions to.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your command line recognizes mysql command. If not go to command and type in

set path=c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin
Then use this command to export your database

Go to directory where you have mysql. -u - for username -p - to prompt the password

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u Username -pPassword DatabaseName > DatabaseName.sql
```

Note:It is better to use full path of the the sql file file.sql

To export database from dump file (in this case called filename.sql) use: mysql -u username -p password database_name > filename.sql

If you are on Windows you will need to open CMD and go to directory where mysql.exe is installed. If you are using WAMP server then this is usually located in: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin (*note the version of mysql might be different)

So you will: cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin

and then execute one of the above commands.